# Accidentally executed reset master on the live server

Tags: mysql, replication

Turns out I have called `RESET MASTER;` accidentally on the live server. The slaves stopped replication now because they can not find the expected bin log files on the master. Is there a way to continue replication without data corruption and without reimporting the whole dump on the slave?

Is it save to call `CHANGE MASTER TO...` with 'mysql-bin.000001' and position 1 on the slave now, because that is where they should continue, or do I risk data corruption in that case and it is generally preferred to reimport the whole dump and start over?

Comment: Do not go back to the start, unless you have really replicated nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering all the slaves were in-sync with master while you issued reset-master, it is safe to issue `change master to` on slaves with newly generated first bin-log.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to find out if they were in sync? Considering this is a live environment with hundreds of requests per minute, there might be a chance that a transaction has been executed just before I called `RESET MASTER` and before the slaves could read it, right?

Comment: it is possible that your reset master have erased the data before it got replicated... check for error log for more information about last binary log co-ordinates and match it with slaves... if not... Restoring slave is a sure shot here but if not possible or if data's too large you may checksum/sync your data.

Comment: makes sense, thank you. restoring from scratch now, just to be sure.